# How to get specific element from page to variable in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have this kind of cookie in code on page. I would like to get language out of it.

I mean how could I this function return in this example "en" in GTM variable:

```
function() {return ...}
```

Code in page looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="wtml-cookie-js-extra">
var wtml_cookies = {"wp-wtml_current_language":{"value":"en","expires":1,"path":"\/"}};
var wtml_cookies = {"wp-wtml_current_language":{"value":"en","expires":1,"path":"\/"}};</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Global variables](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/global-variable) like that are accessible in the `window` object.  This code should do it:

```js
function() {
  return window.wtml_cookies["wp-wtml_current_language"]["value"];
}
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you!